# Turn two columns into tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

Okay so right now I have two columns that display a bunch of posts and data. Right now on Desktop I have them floating left and right. What Im looking to do is to turn those columns into tabs when on mobile. So for insance it goes from desktop like this

```
column1                   column2
 11111                     22222
 11111                     22222
 11111                     22222
```

to when it is on mobile it would go

***column1***|colum2

1111

1111

1111

Then I could click on the column2 tab and I would see the posts show for column2.

Here is how I have my page setup

```
 <section className-"dash">
  <section className="dashboard-container-left">
      <section className="myRecommended">
        .........
        .........
      </section>
  </section>
  <section className="dashboard-container-right">
      <section className="usersRecommended">
        .........
        .........
      </section>
  </section>
 </section>
```

And again I just have both floating left and right.

Comment: is `.dashboard-container-left` and `.dashboard-container-right` the left and right columns you want to turn into tabs?

Comment: Yes sorry I wasnt clear about that part. But yes, those are the two columns Im looking to turn into tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using CSS only. By utilising the `:checked` and `~` selectors you can style sibling elements based on the radio button selection.

You'll need to hide the labels when not in your mobile view.

```css
.tab-panel {
  /* apply these styles in mobile ony */
  float: none;
  display: none;
}

input[name="tabs"] {
  display: none;
}

input[name="tabs"]:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[id="tab1"]:checked ~ .tab-panel#col1 {
  display: block;
}

input[id="tab2"]:checked ~ .tab-panel#col2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash">
  <!-- Only display labels on mobile -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked>  
  <label for="tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="col1">Col 1</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">  
  <label for="tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="col2">Col 2</label>  
  
  <section class="tab-panel dashboard-container-left" id="col1">
    1111<br>
    1111<br>
    1111<br>
  </section>
  <section class="tab-panel dashboard-container-left" id="col2">
    2222<br>
    2222<br>
    2222<br>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This was perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method that uses some psuedo selectors like `:not()` and `:target`

The downside to this is that by default neither column is shown, so that may not be what you wanted for this page.

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs .tab {
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: grey
}

.tabs .tab a {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs .tab a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tabs .tab a:link {
  color: grey;
}

.tabs .tab+.tab {
  border-width: 0 0 2px 1px;
}

.tab-panel:target {
  display: block;
}

.tab-panel:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash">
  <!-- Only display labels on mobile -->
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <a href="#col1">
        Column 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <a href="#col2">
        Column 1
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="tab-panel" id="col1">
    1111<br> 1111
    <br> 1111
    <br>
  </section>
  <section class="tab-panel" id="col2">
    2222<br> 2222
    <br> 2222
    <br>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya Im looking for it to show right away. But definitely a great starting point to get me there. Thank you!